# wordpress custom field add read more link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with the query of get_post_meta.. I'm trying to trim the length of a custom field text and add a read more in the end of the text. I'm using this code

```
$trim_length = 20; 
$value_more = '(...)';
$custom_field = 'description';
$description = get_post_meta($post ->ID, 'description', true);
if ($description) {
echo wp_trim_words($description, $trim_length, $value_more);
}
```

I would like to get the option to expand the text field instead of open a new link.

I hope you can help me..

Comment: I think you are looking for.   `the_excerpt()` this is one of the wordpress function call in side the post loop.

Comment: Thank you jitendra yadav i will take a look on that..